# How to Add related object to the context in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two classes

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public A A { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

the ICollection could be null so first I create and add objects of type A in the following way. First of all I have a generic method for adding items:

```
public void Add<T>(T item)
{
    using ( var context = new DbContext())
    {
        context.Set<T>().Add(obj);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
A objA = new A() { Name = "Object A" };
Add<A>(objA);
```

So far everything works fine. My problem comes when adding related object of type B.

```
B objB = new B() { Name = "Object B", A = objA }
Add<B>(objB);
```

Adding objB results in duplicating objA (with different Id). I'm not sure where I'm wrong. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly why it's hardly ever helpful to have this layer of wrappers around `DbContext` and `DbSet`.

The only thing your `Add` method can do well is, add a *single* `A` entity to the database, *and any entity that's connected to it* (also called an *object graph*). The method `DbSet.Add` that's used inside of it marks every entity as `Added` that is (1) reachable from the `A` instance and (2) that's not yet attached to the context. Well, you create the context inside the method, so there's no way for nested entities to get attached before `A` is added.

But this isn't your only problem. You also can't add more entities (not even more than one `A` entity) to the database in one transaction unless you wrap all `Add` calls in a `TransactionScope`. No way to use one `SaveChanges` call to commit one complete unit of work.

I don't know where this `Add` method resides, but you should somehow refactor your code so as to have more freedom to manipulate the object graph before saving changes.

Without any wrappers this task would be done like so:

```
using(var context = new MyContext())
{
    A objA = context.As.Find(id); // id is a variable holding an existing A's Id

    // Now objA is attached to the context and won't be added.
    B objB = new B() { Name = "Object B", A = objA };
    context.Bs.Add(objB);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a foreign key property in your classes:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<B> { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("A")]
    public int AId { get; set; }    
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

In this way, you can set the reference key ID instead of the whole object when creating a B type.

```
B objB = new B() 
{ 
    Name = "Object B",
    AId = objA.Id // Set object ID here
};

Add<B>(objB);
```

Hope it can help you!

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to use [`context.Attach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.attach?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    // 'a' is an existing object, to link to it we only need to specify its Id
    var a = new A { Id = 3 };
    context.Attach(a);

    var newBObj = new B { A = a };
    context.Set<B>().Add(newBObj);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here are more examples: https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships/managing-one-to-many-relationships#attach-a-fake-representing-the-principal-then-add-the-dependent-to-it